# Rally feature/page visitor counter

Tags: counter, rally, visitor-pattern

my first post. I am using Rally, and have a lot of pages at the moment. I want to see of the pages that I have, how many of them are being used, if they are not I want to get rid of them to make Rally more cleaner. Is there a bit of custom code/APi that anyone has that can be implemented into Rally easily to let me see how many times pages or Rally features are being accessed
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible to do using the Rally Webservice's API.